# Is there a verb that means “to make poor”?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, derivation

Is there a verb that means *to make poor,* such as a derivative form of the adjective *poor*? If not, what would be its best alternative?

Comment: Give us a sentence in which you would use this word.

Comment: Perhaps *impoverish* would be close enough?

Comment: To make poor ot to become poor.

Comment: Please look up a good dictionary that shows the different word forms of *poor*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP hasn't explained what meaning he intends for ***to poor***. To ***make** [someone else] poor, **become** poor [oneself], **judge** [something to be] poor*, etc.

Comment: how about rob??

Comment: @sunk818 If someone robs you, it will surely make you poor**er**, but it will not necessarily make you **poor**.

Answer (score 7):

You might try

- **[impoverish](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impoverish)** (to make poor; to deprive of strength, richness, or fertility by depleting or draining of something essential),
- **[pauperize](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pauperize)** (to reduce to poverty), or
- the verb form of **[beggar](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beggar)** (to reduce to poverty or the practice of asking for charity)

all of which mean "to make poor."

*Definitions by Merriam-Webster.*

Comment: I like the verbs in this answer, but the definitions ought to be included in it.

Comment: The definitions are linked to.  Just middle-click if you want to open in a new tab.  Also see the question for the meaning of the words.

Comment: External web pages are ephemeral; quoting the definitions will aid in the long-term utility of your answer.

Comment: Agreed with @Anonym: please [quote the relevant definitions in your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/273503), and [tell us which dictionary they came from](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4981/55623).

Comment: You can hover over the links to see which dictionary is being linked to (Merriam-Webster, which I use because not everyone has access to OED) and the definition is as noted in the question.  

See new discussion at http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/6951/when-definitions-are-linked-to-is-copy-pasting-the-definitions-required

Comment: Regardless of the discussion on meta, I agree with @Anonym and Dan Bron. Nobody wants to go off to three links to see if your answer is correct or pertinent. A good answer requires the effort to present it so users can see how these words are used and have this pointed out to them. For example impoverish is more common than pauperize (assuming they have the same meaning) and beggar is more extreme than impoverish. Also I don't think "How about?" is the way to phrase an answer. It is better to say that you suggest something, indicate the meaning, and then ask if it is suitable.

Answer (score 2):

What about "to ruin someone"? I think it means exactly the same as "to make someone poor", plus it sounds better.
I hope I helped
Have a good one